# print pdf with javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

I know that there are a lot of questions about this, but I test all and not fix my problem. I have the following code:

```
var datauri = //PDF in base64
popup = window.open("", "Your PDF","width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,copyhistory=no,id='printPDF'");       
popup.document.location.href = datauri;//show pdf in other page
popup.print();//print pdf
```

But, when I print the PDF, the page appear empty, but when I close the window of print, show the PDF, I tried with a lot of stuff, but nothing works, please help me :(

Comment: Can you 1) format the code properly (makes answering easier, although I can decipher what's there), 2) tell me what OS, browser and PDF plugin you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wait a minute, I think I see what *might* go wrong.

The `datauri` variable is effectively the URL of the popup. But you're using it wrong.

First, take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open).

```
var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
```

As you can see, the first argument is `strUrl`, an URL for the new popup. You give an empty argument, which isn't good to begin with.

What happens, is probably this:

1. The popup gets created.
2. The data URL is passed to the popup. The PDF starts loading in the background.
3. The print dialog comes up, which finds an empty document (the PDF hasn't loaded yet) and thus prints an empty page.
4. The PDF finishes loading, at which point you can print it (after you dismissed the first popup).

So, instead of doing this:

```
popup.document.location.href = datauri;
```

You should pass the `datauri` as the first argument to `window.open`, which is an empty string in your code fragment.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with this code, but not show the window for print :(, any idea?

var datauri = //PDF IN BASE64
    popup = window.open(datauri, "Details of Patients","width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,copyhistory=no,id='printPDF' ");   

    
popup.print();

Comment: Ok, then it probably needs some better solution. You can try this: `popup.addEventListener('load', function () { popup.print() } );`. It's still a bit hackish, but it might work.

Comment: If you post what OS, browser, and PDF plugin you're using, I might be able to help you more.